# Converting Uint8Array into Stream with Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, stream

What's the best way to take a native JavaScript `Uint8Array` and turn it into a readable or transform `Stream`?

I figured out how to turn Uint8Array's into Buffers, not sure if this helps:

```
var uint8array = new Uint8Array();
var buffer = new Buffer(uint8array);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [standard way](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1) would be to define a readable stream with a `_read` method:

```
var Stream = require('stream');

var myStream = new Stream.Readable();
var i = 0;
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

myStream._read = function(size) {
  var pushed = true;
  while (pushed && i < data.length) {
    pushed = this.push(data[i++]);
  }

  if (i === data.length) {
    this.push(null);
  }
};

myStream.pipe(somewhere);
```

However, you can also use [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream)'s `readArray` method:

```
var es = require('event-stream');
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var myStream = es.readArray(data);

myStream.pipe(somewhere);
```

Comment: Trying the "Standard Way" I get an error: "TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk". I'm piping it to process.stdout as a test. Am I doing something wrong, or is this broken?

Answer (score 3):

What made it work for me was using `Duplex` instead of `Readable` (credit goes to [Brian Mancini](http://derpturkey.com/buffer-to-stream-in-node/) ):

```js
import { Duplex } from 'stream';
// Or non ES6 syntax:
// const Duplex = require('stream').Duplex
let stream = new Duplex();
stream.push(buffer);
stream.push(null);
stream.pipe(process.stdout);
```